# BeautifulSoup text search, exact vs. like, from a list of stats

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a number of pages containing statistics in lists that I am scraping. Everything is working except this one minor issue I cannot seem to resolve. In using the text of the data fields to find them, one heading that is very similar to another picks up the wrong value. Anyone know how to correct for this?

HTML looks like this:

```
<li><span class="bp3-tag p p-50">50</span> <span class="some explaining words.">Positioning</span>
<li><span class="bp3-tag p p-14">14</span> <span class="some other explaining words.">BB Positioning</span>
```

Code looks like this, and the output returns 14 for both values when it should return 50 for Positioning and 14 for BB Positioning...

```
stats = ['Positioning', 'BB Positioning']
url = urlopen(req)
soups = bs(url, 'lxml')
def statistics(soups):
    data = {}
    divs_without_skill = soups[1].find_all('div', {'class': 'col-3'})
    more_lis = [div.find_all('li') for div in divs_without_skill]
    lis = soups[0].find_all('li') + more_lis[0]
    for li in lis:
        for stats in fifa_stats:
            if stats in li.text:
                data[stats.replace(' ', '_').lower()] = str(
                    (li.text.split(' ')[0]).replace('\n', ''))
    return(data)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show url ?

Comment: Revised HTML: the bp3-tags change/update relative to the number in question...

Comment: URL: https://sofifa.com/player/244042/moussa-djitte/210049

Comment: can you highlight the numbers which you are trying to extract?

Comment: the ones in red/orange. 50 and 14 to the respective labels, Positioning and BB Positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = {x.h5.text: [i.text for i in x.select(
        '.bp3-tag')] for x in soup.select('div.column.col-3')[7:-1]}
    pp(goal)


main('https://sofifa.com/player/244042/moussa-djitte/210049')
```

Output:

```
{'Attacking': ['56', '71', '64', '62', '53'],
 'Skill': ['72', '46', '29', '36', '70'],
 'Movement': ['78', '79', '83', '65', '74'],
 'Power': ['67', '77', '74', '70', '59'],
 'Mentality': ['51', '29', '69', '57', '65', '55'],
 'Defending': ['33', '14', '16'],
 'Goalkeeping': ['8', '8', '6', '15', '13']}
```

Comment: See above edits. I've tried using the bp3-tags, but they're unique, inconsistent

Comment: @mayord check updated answer, also am not sure if i understood your question correctly.

Comment: So, this query definitely worked as written. But it did not integrate well with all the other items I was pulling. So, I came up with a 'good enough' solution. Thanks for the help